# Fixing top section in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to fix the top section of the dashboard here. Right now, the widgets (selectinput) are fixed, but when the user scroll down, it gets covered by the datatable. Can we not make sure this does not get covered and only datatable moves down?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(fluidRow(
    div(column(12, align="center",
           selectInput("rmd1", "RMDw", choices = c(1,2)),
           selectInput("rmd2", "RMD2", choices = c(1,2))
    ), style = "position:fixed; width:inherit;")
  )),
  br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),
  dataTableOutput("uioutput", height = "2000px")
  
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$uioutput <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CSS z-index property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to control the stack order the HTML elements:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(fluidRow(
    div(column(12, align="center",
               selectInput("rmd1", "RMDw", choices = c(1,2)),
               selectInput("rmd2", "RMD2", choices = c(1,2))
    ), style = "position:fixed; width:inherit; z-index: 1; background-color: white;")
  )),
  br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),
  dataTableOutput("uioutput", height = "2000px")
  
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$uioutput <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another approach is using [position: sticky;](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the style line to `position:absolute` makes it so that the selection boxes scroll up and out of the page when you scroll down, if that's what you were looking for.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(fluidRow(
    div(column(12, align="center",
           selectInput("rmd1", "RMDw", choices = c(1,2)),
           selectInput("rmd2", "RMD2", choices = c(1,2))
    ), style = "position:absolute; width:inherit;")
  )),
  br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),
  dataTableOutput("uioutput", height = "2000px")
  
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$uioutput <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you're trying to make the table stay in place and scroll down through the table, use `DTOutput()` and `renderDataTable()` instead of `dataTableOutput()` and `renderDataTable()`. Then, get rid of `datatable()` inside `renderDT()` and just use 'iris'. Finally, you can add the `Scroller` extension and an options list with `scrollY` and `scroller`. Others may be able to explain the difference between DT and DataTable (this page might help as well: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html), but I believe `DTOutput` and `renderDT` are more flexible. Note: you can add horizontal scrollbars as well with `scrollX` if you use a table with more fields in the future.

Updated code is below.

Hope either of these helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(fluidRow(
    div(column(12, align="center",
           selectInput("rmd1", "RMDw", choices = c(1,2)),
           selectInput("rmd2", "RMD2", choices = c(1,2))
    ), style = "position:absolute; width:inherit;")
  )),
  br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),
  DTOutput("uioutput", height = "600px")
  
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$uioutput <- renderDT({
    iris
  },
    extensions = c('Scroller'),
    fillContainer = T,
    options = list(deferRender = T,
                   scrollY = 400,
                   scroller = T)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: THanks for the efforts. But looks like neither helps.  In your second code, you have kept the scroll to the data itself. But i was looking for the webpage scroll :)